# select only columns containing values (Oracle - apex)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

For example i have table with 5 columns where 2 columns don't contain a value. I want to show only columns with value in my Apex report and hide mentioned 2 columns from report. How to achieve it? Is it possible only with sql query? Or i need to use pl/sql dynamic content?

Comment: "where <your column name> is not null"

Comment: it does not work. My table contain 5 columns and i need hide 2 columns with no values

Comment: @OldProgrammer - that will not work, OP wants to hid columns, not rows

Comment: Seems to me, you will need to get the counts of the records for each column and then hide the relevant column. Alternatively, not sure if possible, have a summary column/row/field and use javascript ? to check the value in the summary columns and hide the same.

Comment: @user7294900 i don't now which columns will be null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to look at every row in the report's results to know whether or not to show the column - this may not perform well, but it can be done.  On each column you would need to create a server-side condition of type "no rows returned" with a SQL query like:

```
select 1
  from my_table
 where (report where clause)
   and this_column is not null
```

Note that `this_column` needs to be the name of the column you are putting the condition on, and `(report where clause)` is the same where clause that the report itself has.

Comment: I have tried it with emp table but i got error: ORA-06550: line 4, column 2: ORA-00936: missing expression.  `select 1
  from emp
 where (select ename,job,mgr from emp) 
 AND ename IS NOT NULL;`

Comment: Yes your SQL is quote invalid!  I meant just the `where` clause, not the whole query.  Looks liek you don't have a `where` clause so just need `select 1 from emp where ename IS NOT NULL`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT
  COALESCE(col1, col2, col3) colA,
  COALESCE(col2, col3, col4) colB,
  COALESCE(col3, col4, col5) colC
FROM myTable
```

If the columns are different types you may need to CAST some of them e.g. `TO_CHAR(col1)` rather than `col1`.